# Android Studio 3.1.4 shows unexpected errors

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1.4

I have updated my android studio to 3.1.4. Everything was working fine but after updating the studio, It is showing unexpected errors.

Followed the below steps to resolve,

1. Invalidate cache and re-start.
2. Clean project and re-build.
3. Deleted .idea files and gradle.

But still facing the same issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Below is the screenshot,

[image]

Comment: Try to update your gradle version or BuildTools

Comment: please share the full code

Comment: @deepakkumar  Y do you need the code here?

Comment: may be you have missed some brackets, I got the same error when I missed the corresponding brackets. Also, You didn't add What the error is showing?

Comment: It is not a compilation error. With these errors, I am able to run the application.

Comment: @Arty all ready using build tools 28 and latest gradle.

Comment: Please also add the error what it showing @hasan_shaikh

Comment: Are you inheriting AppCompatActivity?

Comment: @rohiththammaiah yes

Comment: Sync project or you may be missing libraries.

Comment: I did these but still the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove all the dependencies from your app level build.gradle and save it somewhere.

   dependencies {
   }

Your dependencies section will look like this.

2. Sync the project now, and it will fail.
3. Add copy your saved dependencies and add them to your dependencies section.
4. Now go to file -> Sync Project with Gradle File.

Now you wont find any errors.

Answer (score 0):

If your gradle and buildtool is up to date and you sure there is no missing brackets or something like that. Open a new project and copy your code in there. Sometimes android studio makes this weird bugs.